# Good approach to avoid memory leaks

Tags: java, android, mvvm, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I was experimenting MVVM with Android Data binding. My code is as follows:

```
public class ... extends Activity {    
        ...            
        private CommentViewModel viewModel;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, provideLayout());
            viewModel = new CommentViewModel(this);
            binding.setViewModel(viewModel);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            viewModel = null; //setting view model to null to avoid leaks
            super.onDestroy();
        }
}
```

What I was trying to do is that setting my `ViewModel` to null in `onDestroy()` to avoid any possible leaks.

As my `ViewModel` itself registers some `callbacks` with another components and uses `context` that may leak if one of those callbacks are not removed and context is passed somewhere, I decided to setting it null.

But my co-worker opened up an interesting discussion where he said that this is an obsolete practice as 'Effective Java' suggests and this is how you do in C++. He said that a good approach is to remove all the callbacks from ViewModel and not setting it null. Something like:

```
public class ... extends Activity {    
        ...            
        private CommentViewModel viewModel;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            ...//same as above
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            viewModel.removeCallbacks(); //removing all callbacks from view model to avoid leaks
            super.onDestroy();
        }
}
```

Now both approach works fine, but in the first approach I am very much assured that leak won't happen. But as a result, it looks somewhat ugly. The second approach works fine but it forces me to think about all possible leaks that could happen in the `ViewModel`.

This might be a general question : Which approach do you think is better and Why?

Answer (score 0):

## Generally speaking lets JVM do it's job.

There is nothing more irritating than things like

```
System.gc()
```

In production code of big apps. It's job of middleware engineer to tune JVM and how memory is manage - and I'm really speaking as one these people. In your case things are the same, people who develops Android know best how to manage GC in it. You shouldn't write more code if it's not going to make anything cleaner/easier to understand.

## On the other hand

Expirienced programmers should know all the dirty tricks connected with framework (example: stackoverflow.com/questions/13534030/can-a-scheduled-future-cause-a-memory-leak) and how not cancelling, not dereferencing, not closing etc. could make memory leak.

What in your case might be more important is that, you can image that there will be quite complicated callbacks(let's say that they are circular and there are thousand of them), and making your reference null won't make anything easier for GC, but removing callbacks will.

Comment: "making your reference null won't make anything easier for GC, but removing callbacks will." - can you explain a little bit about it. I didn't understand. Aren't both same things?